# How to delete order in admin panel from Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to delete order in admin panel.
How it possible?
Please give me solution.
I used Magento 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this extension
[a link](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-6.html)
I have tried this its work good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install extension which is appropriate to Delete orders.
From Magento you can have Delete Orders Extension. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use **DELETE ORDER** extension which is available in magento store, with this extension you can easily manage and delete order.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I have to alert you to be cautious with this mode because it will delete all the orders without differentiating between test orders with actual ones. So if you, specifically owners of new stores, are considering using this way, please make sure all orders are your unwanted, and no actual orders are in your store, and I suggest that you should take a thorough backup before doing this.

Now, here are the steps for you to follow:

Step 1: Log on PhpMyAdmin

Step 2: Run SQL Query

Here are the queries you need to add in your database to delete all orders:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

TRUNCATE `sales_order`;

TRUNCATE `sales_order_datetime`;

TRUNCATE `sales_order_decimal`;

TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity`;

TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_datetime`;

TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_decimal`;

TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_int`;

TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_text`;

TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_varchar`;

TRUNCATE `sales_order_int`;

TRUNCATE `sales_order_text`;

TRUNCATE `sales_order_varchar`;

TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`;

TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`;

TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`;

TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`;

TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`;

TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`;

TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`;

TRUNCATE `tag`;

TRUNCATE `tag_relation`;

TRUNCATE `tag_summary`;

TRUNCATE `wishlist`;

TRUNCATE `log_quote`;

TRUNCATE `report_event`;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sendfriend_log` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `tag` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `tag_relation` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `tag_summary` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `wishlist` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `log_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

— lets reset customers

TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity`;

TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_datetime`;

TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_decimal`;

TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_int`;

TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_text`;

TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_varchar`;

TRUNCATE `customer_entity`;

TRUNCATE `customer_entity_datetime`;

TRUNCATE `customer_entity_decimal`;

TRUNCATE `customer_entity_int`;

TRUNCATE `customer_entity_text`;

TRUNCATE `customer_entity_varchar`;

TRUNCATE `log_customer`;

TRUNCATE `log_visitor`;

TRUNCATE `log_visitor_info`;

ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `customer_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `log_customer` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `log_visitor` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `log_visitor_info` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

— Now, lets Reset all ID counters

TRUNCATE `eav_entity_store`;

ALTER TABLE `eav_entity_store` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

When finished, all orders are deleted in your site!